# how to display all PlaceMarks/pins on google map in iphone?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, google-maps-markers

friends,

i am new to iphone development and just implement google map in iphone application.
now i am facing a problem with following description

i have list of latitude and longitude values when display them on map those pins are displayed on different locations.

now i want to set zoom level so that all pins are displayed on the screen.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values 3.0 and 2.0 are only examples you can increase or decrease the values according to your requirement(how much you have to zoom)  ,map is my mkmapview object

```
        MKCoordinateSpan span; 
        span.latitudeDelta = 3.0;
        span.longitudeDelta = 2.0;
        MKCoordinateRegion region;      
        region.span = span;     
        [map setRegion:region animated:YES];
        [map regionThatFits:region];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an MKMapView you can use the `setRegion:animated:` method to change the region displayed. I would use `annotationsInMapRect:` to determine which annotations are being shown. Since `annotationsInMapRect:` returns an NSSet you could make an NSSet of all your annotations, and zoom out the MKMapView until the NSSet returned from `annotationsInMapRect:` matches your NSSet of **all** annotations.

Comment: Dear Alan.

thanks a lot for such quick response. as i am new with IPHONE so if you could provide some code sample that would be more helpful for me